# Insert markdown table in roxygen2 R package documentation

Tags: r, markdown, roxygen2

I'm writing an R package and I want to include a table in an R help file, e.g. in the `@details` section. I tried including markdown code directly:

```
#' | Tables        | Are           | Cool  |
#' | ------------- |:-------------:| -----:|
#' | col 3 is      | right-aligned | $1600 |
#' | col 2 is      | centered      |   $12 |
```

But this does not give me the desired output. I have enabled markdown support for the whole package and have roxygen2 6.0.1 installed. Is there no support for markdown tables? Do I have to use `\tabular{}`?

Comment: H. Wickham says this: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html. In my own packages I also use `\ţabular{}` and the syntax is similar to LaTex.

Comment: Currently supported tags: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/markdown.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the `@md` tag to your roxygen chunk

```r
#' @details
#' The table is: 
#'
#' | Tables        | Are           | Cool  |
#' | ------------- |:-------------:| -----:|
#' | col 3 is      | right-aligned | $1600 |
#' | col 2 is      | centered      |   $12 |
#' 
#' @md
```

or add `Roxygen: list(markdown = TRUE)` to your `DESCRIPTION` file.

Answer (score 2):

Note that {roxygen} generates R Documentation files in the end. Thus, you can always go to the [Writing R Extensions: Lists and tables](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Lists-and-tables) and write the table in the native documentation language for R-packages by hand.

Here's a minimal example:

```
\name{dummy}
\title{Dummy}
\details{
  The example here is:
\tabular{lcc}{
  Tables   \tab  Are           \tab Cool   \cr
  col 3 is \tab  right-aligned \tab $1600  \cr
  col 2 is \tab  centered      \tab  $12   \cr
 }
}
```

Note, that the latest {roxygen2} version 7.0 provides more support for markdown-syntax.

Comment: Yes. And with roxygen2 version 7.0 the code in the question should now just work fine.